# How does changing the intrinsicContentSize of a UITableViewCell work?

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout

I made a UITableView with cells that expand when you tap on them. It is modeled off the following project: https://github.com/rushisangani/TableViewCellExpand

Basically, the cell's container view has two subviews which act as containers for the expanded/contracted states - "front" and "back", each of which is constrained to the top, bottom, leading, and trailing edges of the cell's main content view. To make the cell expand or contract, I just toggle the isActive property on the bottom constraint of the front and back views. This works, but only if I reload the cell when it is tapped. If I just change the constraints and then try to call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize(), nothing happens.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        // Expand/contract the cell and invalidate size (doesn't work)
//        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ExpandingCell
//        cell.tap()
//        cell.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

        // Keep track of the selected index and configure the expand/contract state when the cell is remade
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        expandedIndexPath = indexPath
        if(!expandedIndexPathArray.contains(indexPath)){
            expandedIndexPathArray.append(indexPath)
        }
        else{
            expandedIndexPathArray = expandedIndexPathArray.filter({$0 != indexPath})
        }

        // Whenever a cell's intrinsicContentSize changes, it must be reloaded
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
    }
```

What's going on behind the scenes? Why can't the cell recalculate its size without being reloaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to contract/expand cells based on their intrinsic content size, you need to do the following 3 steps:

1. Configure the table view:

   ```
   tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
   tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
   ```

   For static table view controller, you will need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension`.
2. Update cell constraints to reflect contracted/expanded state
3. Ask the table view to reflect changes:

   ```
   tableView.beginUpdates()
   tableView.endUpdates()
   ```

Comment: Sweet, I like that much better than reloading the cell. Why does beginUpdates()/endUpdates() work, but not invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()?

Comment: The intrinsic content size was introduced with Auto Layout in iOS 6. The table view class predates this. It also batches changes with its own animations, etc.

Comment: Is there any decent documentation on how the process of sizing a cell with auto layout works? I know how to actually make cells with auto layout and get things working, but it would be nice to understand the mechanics behind it too. Apple's documentation is kind of crappy in some ways.

Comment: Not that I know of.